# How to track sessions in web application?

Tags: session, spring-mvc

I am new to web design.
So, can anybody tell me how to get information about all opened sessions?
( I am writing a game and i need to know about all clients which are on-line at the moment )
I am using spring Mvc 3.0

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry once more)
i am dealing with my session like this:

```
request.getSession(true).setAttribute("client",client);
        request.getSession(true).setAttribute(Constants.SESS_AUTH, Boolean.TRUE);
```

my listener is

```
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
       totalActiveSessions++;
       System.out.println("sessionCreated - add one client into list");
       setOnline(arg0);
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
       totalActiveSessions--;
       System.out.println("sessionDestroyed - deduct one client from list");
       setOffline(arg0);
}

private void setOnline(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent){

      HttpSession session = sessionEvent.getSession();

      ApplicationContext ctx =
            WebApplicationContextUtils.
                  getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());

      SessionService sessionService = (SessionService) ctx.getBean("sessionService");

      sessionService.setClientOnLine((Client)sessionEvent.getSession().getAttribute("client"));
}

private void setOffline(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent){

      HttpSession session = sessionEvent.getSession();

      ApplicationContext ctx =
            WebApplicationContextUtils.
                  getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());

      SessionService sessionService = (SessionService) ctx.getBean("sessionService");

      sessionService.setClientOffLine((Client)sessionEvent.getSession().getAttribute("client"));
}
```

unfortunately it doesnt works like i want...
could you recommend something

Comment: problem solved 
just needed to implement HttpSessionAttributeListener